# Different descent methods to bound the rank of an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find out as much as possible about different descent methods to bound the rank of an elliptic curve.

Currently I understand and am able to apply the 'Descent via 2-isogeny' method.

I've also heard of a '$\textit{complete}$ 2-isogeny' method (?) and a 'descent via 3-isogeny' method.

My question is, firstly, does anyone know of any links that explain these two other methods preferably with concrete examples of the application?

Secondly, are there any other descent methods? I believe there are but I have struggled to find a comprehensive list.

Any links to help me understand any of these or any other way of bounding the rank of an elliptic curve would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method you have heard of is "complete $2$-descent". There are examples of this in Chapter X of Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (see Prop 1.4 and the following example).

When $E$ has a $2$-torsion point, one may use descent by $2$-isogeny which appears in $\S 14$ "A $2$-isogeny" of Cassels' *Lectures on Elliptic Curves* (also as Proposition 4.9 of Silverman chapter X).

The more general method of $n$-descent exists. Searching google for "$n$-descent" for some fixed $n$ probably gives a reference. There is a paper of Stoll called *Descent on Elliptic Curves* which discusses the general case, and also a paper of Schaefer and Stoll *How to do a $p$-Descent on an Elliptic Curve*.

To understand this you should be familiar with Chapter X of Silverman, and be comfortable with complete $2$-descent. It is a useful exercise to specialise to $2$-descent (which encompasses "complete $2$-descent") and compute some examples within this framework.

Comment: Thank you for this, really helpful. May I ask, do you know what the 'n' in 'n-descent' refers to?

Comment: Since we can easily compute the Torsion subgroup it is enough to determine (the size of) $E(K)/nE(K)$ in order to compute the rank of $E$. The $n$ in $n$-descent is the one for which we are trying to compute this group (or more specifically, the corresponding $n$-Selmer group).